# Atribuir valor recebido do $.ajax à variavel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

É possível associar um valor recebido por `$.ajax` a uma variável global, pois a partir desses valores, preciso somá-los e mostrá-los em outra tabela. Já tentei porém sempre interpreta com variável local, perdendo seu valor no final da função.

Segue código **JS**:

```
function buildTableNI(){ 

   $('#tb_ni').empty();
    $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       crossDomain:true,
       url:'http://www.minhaurl.com.br/api/meuphp.php?callbackpni=?',
       dataType:'jsonp',
       data: {currency: $('#cur').val()},
       beforeSend: function(){
           $('#loading').css("display","block");
           $('table[name=tb_ni]').css("opacity","0.01"); 
       }    

    }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
           $('#loading').css("display","none");
           $('table[name=tb_ni]').css("opacity","1");

           $('#tb_ni').append('<tr> <td class="column_st">'+'Active'+
                                '</td><td class="column_qtd">'+data.ni_qtdA+
                                '</td><td id="" class="a">'+data.ni_active+
                                '</td><td>'+data.ni_p_active+'</td></tr>');
// quero pegar esses valores (data.ni_active,
//data.ni_p_active,etc e colocar seu valor em uma varivel global.)

           a = $('#ac3').append(parseInt(data.ni_qtdA));


           $('#tb_ni').append('<tr> <td class="column_st">'+'Inactive'+
                                '</td><td class="column_qtd">'+data.ni_qtdI+
                                '</td><td id="a3" class="i">'+data.ni_inactive+
                                '</td><td>'+data.ni_p_inactive+'</td></tr>');

           $('#tb_ni').append('<tr> <td class="column_st">'+'Won'+
                                '</td><td class="column_qtd">'+data.ni_qtdW+
                                '</td><td class="w">'+data.ni_won+
                                '</td><td>'+data.ni_p_won+'</td></tr>');

           $('#tb_ni').append('<tr> <td class="column_st">'+'Budget'+
                                '</td><td class="column_qtd">'+data.ni_qtdB+
                                '</td><td class="b">'+data.ni_budget+
                                '</td><td>'+data.ni_p_budget+'</td></tr>');

           $('#tb_ni').append('<tr> <td class="column_st">'+'Coming'+
                                '</td><td class="column_qtd">'+data.ni_qtdC+
                                '</td><td  class="b">'+data.ni_coming+
                                '</td><td>'+data.ni_p_coming+'</td></tr>');

           $('#tb_ni').append('<tr> <td class="column_st">'+'In Process'+
                                '</td><td class="column_qtd">'+data.ni_qtdP+
                                '</td><td class="p">'+data.ni_process+      
                                '</td><td>'+data.ni_p_process+'</td></tr>');

           $('#tb_ni').append('<tr> <td class="column_st">'+'N/I'+
                                '</td><td class="column_qtd">'+data.ni_qtdNI+
                                '</td><td class="ni">'+data.ni_ni+
                                '</td><td>'+data.ni_p_ni+'</td></tr>');

           $('#tb_ni').append('<tr class="head_table"> <td>'+'Total'+
                                '</td><td class="column_qtd">'+data.ni_qtd_total+
                                '</td><td  class="total">'+data.ni_total+
                                '</td><td>'+data.ni_p_total+'</td></tr>');

           $('#tb_ni').append('<tr> <td class="column_st">'+'Replaced'+
                                '</td><td class="column_qtd">'+data.ni_qtdR+
                                '</td><td  class="r">'+data.ni_replaced+
                                '</td><td>'+' - '+'</td></tr>');




    })
     .fail(function(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Erro na operação.");
        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });

   return false; 
}
```

Resumindo, preciso pegar esses valores(`data`) recebidos no `.done` e atribuí-los para variáveis globais, pois tenho mais funções que precisam desses valores para serem somados.

**EDIT:**
Tentei fazer usando `window.variavel_global` nesse trecho:

```
}).done(function(data){
        window.vg = data.ni_active;
            console.log("variavel global:"+(vg));
```

Até mostra no console, porém quando vou checar no console o valor dessa variável fora desse função, assim:

```
console.log( window.vg);
```

Não dá certo e retorna **undefined** no console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar uma variável global mas tens de ter em conta que essa variável só recebe o seu valor **depois** do ajax ter terminado. Ou seja ela fica com estado `undefined` até receber valor dentro do `.done()` pois o ajax pode demorar vários segundos a completar. Isto é assíncronismo, e a solução é chamares a função que precisa da variável com os dados do ajax **dentro** do `.done()`. E assim, na prática nem precisas da variável global...

Seria algo assim:

```
}).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        minha_funcao_que_precisa_da_resposta_do_ajax(data); // e aqui passas os dados que precisavas
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variável assim:

```
window.VariavelGlobal
```

Como se sabe, JavaScript tem dois tipos de variáveis, as globais e as locais. As variáveis locais são declaradas dentro do escopo de uma função, já as variáveis globais têm seu valor acessível em qualquer parte do programa, com isso vem um problema: suas variáveis globais podem ser sobrescritas por basicamente qualquer outra variável e por qualquer objeto de [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

Exemplo 1 (funciona, `variavel_global` é global e pode ser acessada de fora da função). Outra aproximação é remover qualquer prefixo `var` ou `window.`, deixando somente o nome da variável:

```js
$(function(){
    function exemplo( data ){
        //poderia ser somente-> variavel_global = data;
        window.variavel_global = data;
    }
    
    exemplo('Valor de [data]');
    
    console.log(variavel_global);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Exemplo 2 (não funciona, `variavel_local` é local e só pode ser acessada de dentro da função):

```js
$(function(){
    function exemplo( data ){
        var variavel_local = data;
    }
    
    exemplo('Valor de [data]');
    
    console.log(variavel_local);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oi, tentei usar com window e mesmo assim não funcionou. A variável vem vazia, chequei no console.

Comment: Era pra ter funcionado. Adicionei um exemplo no código.

Comment: Não deu certo mesmo assim :(
Editei minha pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

ou pode usar um callbak:

```js
var myvar = null;

function buildTableNI(callback){ 

   $('#tb_ni').empty();
    $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       crossDomain:true,
       url:'http://www.minhaurl.com.br/api/meuphp.php?callbackpni=?',
       dataType:'jsonp',
       data: {currency: $('#cur').val()},
       beforeSend: function(){
           $('#loading').css("display","block");
           $('table[name=tb_ni]').css("opacity","0.01");
       }

    }).done(function(data){
           //código de início de done()
          var retorno = {
            ni_active: data.ni_active,
            ni_p_active : data.ni_p_active
          }
          
          //chamada callback
          callback(retorno)
          
    //o resto de código vai aqui


    })
     .fail(function(data, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //função fail
    });

   return false;
}

buildTableNI(function(data){
    myvar = data;
});
```